# How do you say "merge conflicts" in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

From [github](https://help.github.com/en/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line):

Merge conflicts occur when competing changes are made to the same line of a file, or when one person edits a file and another person deletes the same file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après Wikipédia, le concept est traduit par [conflit de modifications](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestion_de_versions#Conflit_de_modifications).

D'autre part, comme beaucoup de termes en informatique, l'emprunt à l'anglais est courant.

Answer (score 9):

La traduction française du livre [*Pro Git*](https://git-scm.com/book/fr/v2) (deuxième édition, 2014, Scott Chacon et Ben Straub, *Apress*, cc-nc-sa 3.0) parle de [**conflits de fusions**](https://git-scm.com/book/fr/v2/Les-branches-avec-Git-Branches-et-fusions%C2%A0%3A-les-bases) pour *merge conflicts*.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the accepted answer. But most of the time we'll simply say "merge conflict" or "conflict", because we use anglicisms a lot :)

Comment: Yep I've already upvoted you answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Dans ma vie de codeur de tous les jours, je dis *conflit de merge*.

Je sais que c'est un anglicisme, mais si j'utilise n'importe quel mot français censé traduire le concept, j'observe de grands yeux ronds chez mes interlocuteurs.

Comment: @Survenant9r7: Vous avez raison. Mais si je leur dis qu'ils sont doublement nuls, ça ne va pas aider à les convertir et j'aurai perdu mon temps.

Answer (score 1):

Il est possible de dire:

- conflit de conciliation
- conflit de modification
- conflit de fusions